# Google Static maps maximum size on Android device

Tags: android, google-maps-static-api

I have portrait oriented android application. There is static map with width="match_parent".
For devices with screen width bigger than 640 pixels - map is not big enough.
Is it good idea to enlarge map?

Comment: What is exactly that you want ??

Comment: To show static map as row in ListView. ListView is wide as screen width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem (map was not big enough), and this is how I solved it :

```
// Used WindowManager to get screen size, because this was a customview.
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;

String lat = YOUR_LAT;
String lng = YOUR_LNG;

String mapEndpoint = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lng + "&zoom=17&size=" + width/2 + "x" + height/2 + "&scale=2";
```

Basically I used `scale` and divided `width` and `height` by the same `scale` value. You'll get  full screen of map with above code.

I still feel it was pretty hacky, so if there's anyone who knows the correct way, please give me a comment!

Comment: Thx , better hack !